# Combine queries to multiple tables having the same columns in to one query

Tags: postgresql, grails

I have 6 tables. All of them can have millions and millions of lines of data. All of the tables have object_id, changer_id, date_created columns.

I need to make a query on all of the tables

```
SELECT object_id
FROM table#
WHERE changer_id=someId
AND date_created > dateA
AND dateCreated < dateB
```

or its grails equivalent

```
table#.createQuery().list{
        projections{property('object_id')}
        eq('changer_id', someId)
        ge('dateCreated' dateA)
        le('dateCreated', dateB)
}
```

Same query will be made on all of the 6 tables, and then the results are combined and all duplicates are removed.

Im not using between because dateB might not always exist so it would be ommited.

Is there a way to combine this query into single query over 6 tables or any other way to make it faster than 6 separate queryes?

Comment: a union query could do that https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-union.html - in the end you can always the DataSource and do it yourself.

Comment: @cfrick I "can always the Datasource"? I think there are some words missing. And with union, it will still do 6 different querys it just combines them in the end, is it any fater than doing the 6 queries separately and then combinign them ?

Comment: "you can always inject the DS"; and most likely that it's faster, because the DB does all the work and just returns the least amount of data.  but of course: performance must be measured and not cargo culted.

Comment: " And with union, it will still do 6 different querys it just combines them in the end". That is false

Comment: SQL inheritance

Answer (score 0):

SQL inheritance:

assuming your tables are `table1`, `table2`, etc,

setup: do this once:

```
create table combined ( like table1 );

alter table table1 inherits combined;
alter table table2 inherits combined;
alter table table3 inherits combined;
alter table table4 inherits combined;
alter table table5 inherits combined;
alter table table6 inherits combined;
```

the query, do this many times as needed:

```
SELECT object_id
FROM combined
WHERE changer_id=someId
AND date_created > dateA
AND dateCreated < dateB
```

postgresql will internally generate the unions needed.

I'm assuming that all the tables have the same columns, if not  exclude any columns that are missing from some tables when you create the combined table. (you don't have to use `like`... , you can use the more common list-of-columns syntax)